# Second distributional derivative of $P.V. \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, distribution-theory, cauchy-principal-value

I computed first derivation and I get that $$\langle(\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{x})', \varphi\rangle = v.p. \int_{ \mathbb{R}} \frac{\varphi(0) - \varphi(x)}{x^2} dx$$

In order to get second derivative we use $\left<g'', \varphi \right> = \left<g, \varphi''\right> $ but I stuck there since I have just a lot of equations that gives us nothing.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could it be that  $\langle g'',\ \varphi\rangle=\langle g,\ (\varphi')'\rangle$? Since $\langle g',\ \varphi\rangle=-\langle g,\ \varphi'\rangle$ I am thinking in something like:$$\langle \left(\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{x}\right)'',\ \varphi\rangle=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2}dx$$

Comment: @Joako. Yes, with the integral being the principal value integral, that's correct. But you can rewrite the last expression using integration by parts.

Comment: The derivatives of $\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{x}$ can be written in several somewhat different forms. Are you looking for any special form?

Comment: @md2perpe No, it doesn't matter in which form. I just want to understand how to work with second dist derivatives

Comment: @md2perpe Also we can separate our integral and get $\langle(\mathcal{P}\frac{1}{x})', \varphi\rangle = \int_{ \mathbb{R}} \frac{\varphi'(x)}{x^2} dx + \int_{ \mathbb{R}} \frac{\varphi'(0)}{x^2} dx$ , and second intégral = $\frac{\varphi'(0)}{x}$ since $\varphi'(0)$ is const

Comment: @Margaret. Be careful; the second integral isn't convergent at $x=0$ (unless $\varphi'(0)=0$ of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$
\operatorname{pv}\int f(x) \ dx = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} f(x) \ dx.
$$

We define the distribution $\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}$ by
$$
\langle \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}, \varphi \rangle
= \operatorname{pv} \int \frac{\varphi(x)}{x} \ dx
.
$$

For its derivative we get
$$
\langle \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)', \varphi \rangle
= -\langle \operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}, \varphi' \rangle 
= -\operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi'(x)}{x} \ dx
= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi'(x)}{x} \ dx \\
= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
\left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x} \right]_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon} + \left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x} \right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty} + \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \ dx 
\right)\\
= -\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \ dx
= -\operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \ dx
.
$$

For the second derivative we then get
$$
\langle \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)'', \varphi \rangle
= -\langle \left(\operatorname{pv}\frac{1}{x}\right)', \varphi' \rangle
= \operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2} \ dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2} \ dx \\
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(
\left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon}
+ \left[ \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^2} \right]_{\epsilon}^{\infty} \\
+ 2 \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^3} \ dx
\right) \\
= 2\operatorname{pv}\int \frac{\varphi(x)-\varphi'(0)x-\varphi(0)}{x^3} \ dx.
$$

Comment: $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{\varphi'(x)-\varphi'(0)}{x^2} \ dx $ how you solved it? Using partial integration?

Comment: @Margaret. Yes, I used integration by parts to rewrite it.